# Objective-c mac app - Open external URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying open a external link: google.com but I can't, can someone say what I am doing wrong in my code?

Someone can explain me why external links are blocked by default?

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webview;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps: YES];

    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"HTML/content.htm"];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURL*url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://google.com/" ];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    NSURL *htmlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HTML/content" ofType:@"htm"] isDirectory:NO];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlFile];

    [[self.webview mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: It's tagged as iOS, titled with Mac, using `NSWindow`, `NSApplication`... Is `webview` nil? There are two `NSURL *url` in your code, what's your real code?

Comment: One I  am using for open the internal url, so I tried create the another one to open external url, make sense?

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? You can't have UIApplication reference in Mac app.

Comment: If you are on Xcode 7 and get an error like "App Transport Security has blocked" you should insert a new line in info.plist like this:

"App Transport Security Settings" which has a sibling "Allow Arbitrary Loads" which must be set to true. Hope this helps.